# Will Ubuntu 18.04 run on i3-4th gen, 1.7ghz with dual core system?

Tags: system-installation

On the Ubuntu website it mentioned system requirements of 2ghz dual core system. Might it still run on my 1.7GHz processor?

Comment: Why not try before you install?   https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/)? The system requirements are very minimal (Xfce is very light) and it is basically Ubuntu behind the scenes. It is recommended to have 1 GB of ram and a dual core processor for Xubuntu.

As previously mentioned, you could make a bootable Ubuntu USB and try it out first before installing.